# Selenide combines 2 ElementsCollections

Tags: selenium, selenide

I have 2 `ElementsCollections` namely `oddTableRowItems` and `evenTableRowItems`:

```
private static ElementsCollection oddTableRowItems() {
    return $$(By.className("odd"));
}

private static ElementsCollection evenTableRowItems() {
    return $$(By.className("even"));
}
```

I want to combine the 2 in order to only do a for loop once. It is row items, and only there classnames differ for styling purposes and I can only identify them through classnames.

This is how I tried to combine it - but it does not work:

```
ElementsCollection rowElements = evenTableRowItems();
rowElements.addAll(oddTableRowItems());
```

I get an:

> java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException

does anybody how can I combine the 2 `ElementsCollections`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The API could probably be a little bit more friendly here. But this way you can combine two ElementsCollection instances. The key here is `WebElementsCollectionWrapper` class.

```
ElementsCollection evenElements = $$(By.className("even"));
ElementsCollection oddElements = $$(By.className("odd"));
List<SelenideElement> elementsCombined = new ArrayList<>(evenElement);
elementsCombined.addAll(oddElements);
WebElementsCollectionWrapper wrapper = new WebElementsCollectionWrapper(elementsCombined);
ElementsCollection selenideCollectionCombined = new ElementsCollection(wrapper);
```

Answer (score 2):

All `add*` methods throw `UnsupportedOperationException` by design. It's because `ElementsCollections` represents a collection of existing web elements on a web page; and page elements cannot be modified by test. That's why you cannot add or remove elements on the page.

The easiest way is to select all matching elements at once:

```
$$(".odd,.even").shouldHave(size(10));
```

A little bit longer way is to compose a new list containing both collections:

```
List<String> newList = new ArrayList<String>();
newList.addAll($$(".odd"));
newList.addAll($$(".even"));
```

but your goal seems to be doubtful for me. You will get the list with **invalid order**. Why can it be useful? Why would one need to iterate all elements? I cannot imagine a use case for that.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/AbstractList.html#addAll%28int,%20java.util.Collection%29):

> Note that this implementation throws an UnsupportedOperationException unless add(int, E) is overridden.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code. This is work fine!

```
ArrayList<SelenideElement> newList = new ArrayList<SelenideElement>();
newList.addAll(Selenide.$$(By.className("odd"));
newList.addAll(Selenide.$$(By.className("even"));
```